# Awk: Concatenate columns if they are quoted, and remove commas

Tags: awk, csv

I have this data:

```
COL1, COL2, COL3
a, b, c
d, "e,f,g", h
```

I want Awk to treat it as:

```
COL1, COL2, COL3
a, b, c
d, efg, h
```

Each comma-separated string could be any number of characters. I just used single characters here for simplicity.

This doesn't quite work:

```
echo "COL1, COL2, COL3
a, b, c
d, "e,f,g", h" | awk -F ',' '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) gsub(/^"|"$|,/,"",$i); print}'
```

Output:

```
a, b, c
d  "e f g  h
```

Comment: Can your quoted fields contain quotes, e.g. `d, "e,""f"",g", h`? Can they contain newlines? Do you REALLY have blanks after every `,` that's not inside quotes? If so, **that's not valid CSV** as a field is either surrounded by quotes or not, it never starts with other chars like a blank and THEN has quotes, if not then please fix your sample input/output to reflect reality.

Comment: Yes, nested quotes are present. They also can contain newlines. It's the output of `https://github.com/tabulapdf/tabula-java`, which converts pdf to csv. I guess it's not too well-behaved

Comment: Nested quotes (as long as they're escaped `\"` or doubled `""`) and newlines are fine in a CSV, it's spaces after the commas that aren't valid so if it truly is outputting THAT then it's not outputting CSV by any "standard" (i.e. to [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) or as generated by MS-Excel) so YMMV trying to use any tool that can parse CSV to further manipulate that output. If your real input can contain nested quotes and newlines then you should include such in your example and tell us which "newlines" are `\r\n` vs just `\n` alone.

Answer (score 4):

Using `csvformat -S` (or `csvformat --skipinitialspace`) from [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) removes the initial space character after each comma, transforming the data to properly quoted CSV records.  Then [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`) to iterate over each field of each record, removing any embedded comma.

```bash
$ csvformat -S file | mlr --csv put 'for (k,v in $*) { $[k] = gsub(v,",","") }'
COL1,COL2,COL3
a,b,c
d,efg,h
```

Both of these tools are CSV-aware and know how to read CSV records with quoted fields, embedded commas, embedded newlines, etc. Both the csvkit tools and Miller will output quoted fields if the fields need quoting.

For example, adding a record to your data containing a field with a newline and another one with a quote:

```bash
$ cat file
COL1, COL2, COL3
a, b, c
d, "e,f,g", h
My data, "Line 1,
Line 2", "This is a quote: ""The, quote"""
```

```bash
$ csvformat -S file | mlr --csv put 'for (k,v in $*) { $[k] = gsub(v,",","") }'
COL1,COL2,COL3
a,b,c
d,efg,h
My data,"Line 1
Line 2","This is a quote: ""The quote"""
```

Comment: I voted for you. Without installing csvkit `<input.csv | sed -r 's/, +"/,"/g;s/" +,/",/g' | mlr --csv clean-whitespace then put 'for (k,v in $*) { $[k] = gsub(v,",","") }'`

Comment: Cool, I never heard about these tools. The right tools for the job, it seems!

Comment: @aborruso `sed -r 's/, +"/,"/g;s/" +,/",/g'` would corrupt a field like `"foo, ""bar"", etc"` by removing the blanks it contains around the `,`s it contains, turning it into `"foo,""bar"",etc"`

Comment: @EdMorton You're right, but I didn't take this into account, because it just seems to input there is a wrong CSV. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a suitable solution now:

```
'{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i+=1)
    { gsub(/^"|",*$|,/,"",$i);
      printf $i ((i != NF) ? ", " : "\n")
    }
 }'
```

... but this didn't work if fields had spaces in them. This worked:

```
# delimit by comma
-F"," '{
    # m non-zero will tell us if we are in quoted section
    m=0;
    # iterate over every field
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i+=1) {
        # we found a field that starts with possible white-space
        # followed by a quote
        if (match($i,"^ *\"")) {
            # if we are not already in a quoted section, remove the quote, and set 'm'
            if (!m) {sub(/^ *\"/,"",$i)}; m++ }
            # if we are in a quoted section and we encounter a 
            # quote, set 'm' to next lowest-level of quoting
            else if (match($i, "\"")) {m--; 
                # and if we are now outside of the quoted field, remove the quote
                if (!m) {sub("\"","",$i)}};
            # print a comma delimeter unless we're at the last field,
            # in which case we put in a newline
            printf ($i (i==NF? "\n" : (m?"":", ")))
        }
    }
}'
```

Would love to know of a more compact solution!

Comment: That should be giving you a warning message about the `\"`s in your regexps (every `"...\"..."` or `/...\".../` you have in a regexp context in sub() and match() should be `/...".../`) and it'll add extra blanks between fields.

Comment: Never do `printf $i` (for any input string), always do `printf "%s", $i` instead, as the former will fail when your input contains printf formatting characters.

Comment: Hmm I get no warning. Running awk in zsh on MacOS. `awk --version: awk version 20200816`

Comment: Then you might want to get a new awk, e.g. GNU awk.

Answer (score 1):

With any awk if your input really does look like you show with a blank after every comma outside of quotes and no double quotes or newlines inside quoted fields, and no blanks after the commas inside the quoted fields:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=", "} {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) gsub(/[",]/,"",$i)} 1' file
COL1, COL2, COL3
a, b, c
d, efg, h
```

Alternatively with GNU awk for `FPAT` if your input has possible leading blanks in every field and no double quotes or newlines inside quoted fields and possible blanks after commas inside your quoted fields:

```
$ awk -v FPAT='([^,]*)|( *"[^"]+")' -v OFS=',' '
    { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) gsub(/[",]/,"",$i) }
1' file
COL1, COL2, COL3
a, b, c
d, efg, h
```

See [whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk) for more info on parsing CSVs with awk.

Answer (score 0):

This is slightly more compact and takes a different approach. It correctly handles the supplied test data:

```
BEGIN { FS="\"" }

{
    separator = ""
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        if (i % 2) {
            # Odd numbered field, handle as CSV
            n = split($i, parts, ",")
            for (j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
                printf "%s%s", separator, parts[j];
                separator = ","
            }
        }
        else {
            # Even numbered field, handle as quoted text
            gsub(",", "", $i)
            printf "%s", $i;
            separator = ""
        }
    }
    print "";
}
```

I tested it using:

```
COL1, COL2, COL3
a, b, c
d, "e,f,g" , h
"i,j,k"
"l,m",n,o
p,"q"
s, t,u, "w,,z"
```

The above code treats double-quote as the primary separator.  It assumes the quotes are paired, in which case even numbered fields ($2, $4, $6 ...) are quoted, and odd numbered fields ($1, $3, $5, ...) are outside quotes.  Each kind of field, even-quoted/odd-unquoted, is processed differently.

Should it be necessary, escaped-quotes might be able to be handled by using a regular expression as the field-separator (FS). I wasn't sure if all spaces were to be stripped or not, that could be added.